# Behat - ChromeDriver - Mock Geo Location?

Tags: php, drupal, leaflet, behat

I am using Behat to automate a Drupal website that has an embedded Leaflet map, and I need to pass a fake location into the map so I can set "my location".I am having real issues finding an answer to this, can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: So you have started with some pgp, javascript, or behat "code/config" you could show those, that maybe know ...? Maybe provide it with the question?

Comment: The framework is written in PHP, I have just got to a page with an embeded LeafLet map, and can't work out how to interact with it, I need to drag a marker to a location then click on it to set the location..there are no step defintions defined for working with it.

Comment: Leaflet is JS, as i see on their site, maybe you can use some of the methods from their API to create JS scripts and use them in your steps.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look into that, thank you.